# Tool for recording http requests

Tags: web-server, http, unit-tests, go

I'm looking for a tool that provides http requests recording for Golang web server, so that I will be able to use it in integration tests without a need to run client application each time.

I've seen solutions for recording Go client http requests, but in my case client is black-box third party application.

Comment: Some shell scripts with `curl` commands ?

Comment: That seems good. I will dump plain incoming requests and send them for now using curl. I am also checking if plain http requests using Golang client are possible.
Thanks